# Avoid multiple SELECT in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, entity-attribute-value

I'm trying to enhance a SQL bug I found in a merchant website.

I have two tables :

```
------ Table "products" ------
| id_product | product_name |
-----------------------------
|          1 |      T-shirt |
|          2 |     Trousers |
|          3 |  Sweat-shirt |
|          4 |        Socks |

----------- Table "features" -----------
| id_product | feature | feature_value |
----------------------------------------
|          1 |   Color |           Red |
|          1 |    Size |             M |
|          1 |  Fabric |        Cotton |
|          2 |   Color |          Blue |
|          2 |    Size |             S |
|          2 |  Fabric |     Polyester |
|          3 |   Color |           Red |
|          3 |    Size |             L |
|          3 |  Fabric |          Wool |
|          4 |   Color |         White |
|          4 |    Size |             L |
|          4 |  Fabric |        Cotton |
```

I'm trying to retrieve the products with the following features :

- where color is either red or blue
- where size is M
- where fabric is cotton

My query is as follows :

```
SELECT p.id_product
FROM products p
WHERE p.id_product IN (SELECT f.id_product FROM features f WHERE f.feature_value IN ("Red", "Blue"))
    AND p.id_product IN (SELECT f.id_product FROM features f WHERE f.feature_value = "M")
    AND p.id_product IN (SELECT f.id_product FROM features f WHERE f.feature_value = "Cotton")
GROUP BY p.id_product
```

(Of course, in reality, my tables and my query are waaaay more complex than that, I'm just focusing on the problematic part)

The multiple SELECT in the WHERE clause causes my entire server to slow down if 8 or more features are selected.
Is there a way to avoid making this many queries in the WHERE clause ?

EDIT : For instance, here's one of the real queries :

```
SELECT p.id_product id_product
FROM ps_product p 
INNER JOIN ps_category_product cp ON p.id_product = cp.id_product 
INNER JOIN ps_category c ON (c.id_category = cp.id_category AND c.nleft >= 6 AND c.nright <= 7 AND c.active = 1)
LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available sa ON (sa.id_product = p.id_product AND sa.id_shop = 1) 
INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1)
WHERE 1
AND product_shop.active = 1
AND product_shop.visibility IN ("both", "catalog")
AND p.id_manufacturer IN (5,4)
AND sa.quantity > 0
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 82)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 37248)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 181)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 37821)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 33907)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 33902)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 70)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 76)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 291)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 75)
AND p.id_product IN (SELECT id_product FROM ps_feature_product fp WHERE fp.id_feature_value = 44459)
GROUP BY id_product
```

Comment: What about a JOIN and filtering in where?

Comment: In reality, there already are many JOIN in the query, I'd really rather find a solution that would have me edit the WHERE clause only.

Comment: So, many joins means, you won't join the last table because ...?

Comment: why are you using group by?

Comment: I added an example of a real query above. If i used a JOIN, should'nt I add a JOIN for each of my subrequests ? Something like `LEFT JOIN features f1 ON f1.id_product = p.id_product AND f1.feature_value IN ("Red", "Blue") LEFT JOIN  features f2 ON f2.id_product = p.id_product AND f2.feature_value = "M" `and so on ?

Comment: No, if you construct HAVING conditions.

Comment: You are using the dreadful EAV schema design.  Condolences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `JOIN` and `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT p.id_product
FROM products p
JOIN features f
  ON p.id_product = f.id_product
GROUP BY p.id_product
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN f.feature_value IN ('Red', 'Blue') THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN f.feature_value = 'M' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN f.feature_value = 'Cotton' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/TQO81025)**</kbd>

---

Or even shorter (MySQL):

```
HAVING SUM(f.feature_value IN ('Red', 'Blue')) > 0
   AND SUM(f.feature_value = 'M') > 0
   AND SUM(f.feature_value = 'Cotton') > 0;
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of `HAVING`, it seems to work, thanks !

Comment: I like the solution from Pred a lot better; especially if you have a lot of features & values to compare like the OP says. Additionally, I did a little test where I randomly created 5000 products, 200 distinct features and then combined those into into about 1 millon records in the features table with random feature_values. Preds solution runs in about 20ms, this one takes about 280ms and takes up A LOT more CPU because the sorting and grouping is done before the filtering instead of the other way around. (This is after adding PKs and FK and on MSSQL2014, but I think mysql would be alike.)

Comment: @deroby Thanks for the tests and this comment. For the record, my solution has more limitations, than this one. Making it work when the conditions are more complex could be hard or even impossible. (complexity != quantity of conditions tho).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  P.id_product
FROM
  products P
  INNER JOIN features F
    ON P.id_product = F.id_product
WHERE
    (F.featurure = 'Color' AND F.feature_value IN ('red', 'blue'))
    OR (F.featurure = 'Size' AND F.feature_value IN ('M'))
    OR (F.featurure = 'Fabric' AND F.feature_value IN ('Cotton'))
GROUP BY
    P.id_product
HAVING
    COUNT(DISTINCT F.feature) = 3
```

The HAVING condition tells, that there should be at least 3 different matching features (which is the count of your search fields).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Hope it will help.

```
SELECT p.id_product,count(f.feature_value)
FROM products p, features f
where f.id_product=p.id_product 
and f.feature_value in ("Red","Blue") 
or f.feature_value = "M"
or f.feature_value = "Cotton"
group by p.id_product
```